# How to fix args joining together?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The command is `release (link) (what it does)`

I'm bad at explaining but I want it to come out in this form:

```
script thread
link //arg1
what it does
gives perks //arg2
```

but what happens is that it takes from second one:

```
script thread
link gives perks//arg1
what it does
gives perks //arg2
```

```
if (command == "release") {
    if (!message.member.roles.some(r => ["administrator"].includes(r.name))) {
        return message.reply("you are not an admin");
    }
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {
    });
    const channel = message.guild.channels.find("name", "general");
    let arg1 = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    let arg2 = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor("bot", "https://vgy.me/w6DAXP.png")
        .setTitle("script thread")
        .setColor(0x000000)
        .setDescription(arg1)
        .setFooter("bot", "https://vgy.me/w6DAXP.png")
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField("what it does", arg2);
    channel.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). See [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

So, in your case, if,
`args = ['links', 'gives perks']`

Then, `args.slice(0)` will return `['links', 'gives perks']` as `0` is the begin and `args.length` is the end. That is why arg1 is `links gives perks`

You can just use `arg1 = args[0]` and `arg2 = args[1]`

Comment: I would recommend using `arg1 = args.shift() ` and `arg2 = args.join(' ')`